# Concatenate iText Document into a PDF

Tags: jakarta-ee, pdf, itext, concatenation

In my Java EE application, I am generating a PDF through my Action like this:

```
 response.setContentType("application/pdf");
 Document document = new Document();                
 PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream()); 
 processManagerHelper.exportingSystemStatisticsPage(document, foProcess);
```

My function "exportingSystemStatisticsPage" is then opening the document, filling it with iText and JFreeChart, and then closing the document.
This works great.

What I would like to do now, is to call my function "exportingSystemStatistics" several time with different parameters, and concatenate the PDF that the function creates to make only one PDF.
The "exportingSystemStatisticsPage" is creating a one page PDF.

Do you have an idea of how I could do that?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what about setting your first function return type to "ChapterAutoNumber" and concatenate these chapters...?

Comment: I have no return type in my function "exportingSystemStatistics"
This function is used to generate one page PDF, and i would like to keep it that way.
What I would like to do is to create a new function, that calls "exportingSystemStatistics" several times, get all the Document out of it, and concatenate them. But I can't find how...

Comment: if you would add all content which is added to the PDF in "exportingSystemStatistics" to a "ChapterAutoNumber" you can easily concatenate these chapters...

Comment: I started to use the Chapter as you proposed me, it seems to work good.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you would add all content which is added to the PDF in "exportingSystemStatistics" to a [ChapterAutoNumber](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/ChapterAutoNumber.html) you can easily concatenate these chapters...